# Gitlab Runner on Heroku

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I know that someone already asked this question, but I'll ask it again in 2019, does anyone know how to deploy gitlab-runner on heroku,

The reason I'm asking is because my academic institution recently set up gitlab for us, but is lacking gitlab CI, so I'll need to set up a runner if I want CI/CD.

In particular I was wondering how I could use the docker image, https://dev.to/imichael/this-one-trick-gives-you-unlimited-ci-minutes-on-gitlab-e92

```
version: '2'
services:
  dind:
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    volumes:
    - /var/lib/docker
    image: docker:18.06.0-ce-dind
    command:
    - --storage-driver=overlay2

  runner:
    restart: always
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    volumes:
    - ./gitlab/runner:/etc/gitlab-runner:Z
    environment:
    - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://dind:2375

  register-runner:
    restart: 'no'
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    volumes:
    - ./gitlab/runner:/etc/gitlab-runner:Z
    command:
    - register
    - --non-interactived
    - --locked=false
    - --name=Docker Runner
    - --executor=docker
    - --docker-image=docker:18.06.0-ce-dind
    - --docker-volumes=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
    - CI_SERVER_URL=https://XXXXXXXX.XXXXX
    - REGISTRATION_TOKEN=XXXXXXX
```

Comment: How did you get on with this? Looking to do something similar!

Comment: Has anyone been able to achieve this ?

Comment: I think its going to be hard todo and with the free tier changes, likely impossible and not worth the effort.